# ZonedDateTime not displaying Time Zone expected via DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date, java-time, zoneddatetime

I have a date input with a timezone of `EST`.

I'm parsing it to a `ZonedDateTime`, but when formatting, it's being displayed as `GMT-04:00`, rather than `EST` as I'd expect.

Why is this happening - can I get it to display the timezone I expect?

Example

```
final String dateString = "16/07/2017 19:28:33 EST";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Input - {0}", dateString));
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Parsed - {0}", formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter))));
```

Output:

```
Input - 16/07/2017 19:28:33 EST
Parsed - 16/07/2017 19:28:33 GMT-04:00
```

My time zone is GMT. AdoptOpenJDK 14.0.2.12, en_GB locale.

For context, I'm trying to better understand this issue in recent versions of Amazon Corretto 11 - https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/147

Comment: I think you could add `.withZone(ZoneId.of("EST"))` to `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(...)`

Comment: Is GMT-4 the timezone you're currently in?

Comment: @daniu no - I'm in GMT.

Comment: @Savior AdoptOpenJDK 14.0.2.12, en_GB locale.

Comment: I reproduced using `Locale.UK`. Interesting. It parses to`2017-07-16T19:28:33-04:00[America/New_York]`, which is not surprising, but then formats into `16/07/2017 19:28:33 GMT-04:00`, which frankly is to me.

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

You said:

> it's being displayed as GMT-04:00, rather than EST as I'd expect.

Such details depend on whether `Locale.UK` is in effect or not.

- `16/07/2017 19:28:33 GMT-04:00`  ⇐  `Locale.UK`
- `16/07/2017 19:28:33 EDT`        ⇐  `Locale.US`
- `16/07/2017 19:28:33 HAE` ⇐ `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH`

➥ For textual date-time data exchange, (a) stick with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats, and (b) use an offset of zero whenever practical. Doing that makes moot [Issue # 147](https://github.com/corretto/corretto-11/issues/147).

## Details

By the way, try hard to **avoid parsing date-time text using the 2-4 letter pseudo-zones** like `EST`, `EDT`, `IST`, `CST`. These are non-standard, non-unique(!), weak attempts at giving a hint as to the time zone and whether [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) is in effect.

Use only [real time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in format of `Continent/Region` such as `Europe/London`.

---

You said:

> rather than EST as I'd expect

Daylight Saving Time (DST) was in effect on that date-time in time zone of `America/New_York`, not [Standard Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_time). So you should be expecting `EDT` rather than `EST`.

---

I suggest you not complicate matters by embedding calls within your `println` statements.

You should specify the `Locale` rather than rely implicitly on the JVM’s current default locale which can change at any moment during runtime. So notice how I appended `.withLocale( locale )` to the formation of the `DateTimeFormatter` object. I specified `Locale.UK` because you mentioned `en_GB` in a Comment.

So let's modify your code to this:

```java
final Locale locale = Locale.US ;  // Locale.UK versus Locale.US yield different outputs.
final String input = "16/07/2017 19:28:33 EST";
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z" ).withLocale( locale ) ;
final ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( input , formatter ) ;
final String zdtToString = zdt.toString() ;
final String zdtFormatted = zdt.format( formatter ) ;
```

… and:

```java
// Dump to console.
System.out.println( "input: " + input ) ;
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt ) ;
System.out.println( "zdtToString: " + zdtToString ) ;
System.out.println( "zdtFormatted: " + zdtFormatted ) ;
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/SNH7l0) on Java 12.

```java
input: 16/07/2017 19:28:33 EST
zdt: 2017-07-16T19:28:33-04:00[America/New_York]
zdtToString: 2017-07-16T19:28:33-04:00[America/New_York]
zdtFormatted: 16/07/2017 19:28:33 GMT-04:00
```

If we change that locale from `Locale.UK` to `Locale.US`, we get a different result.

```
zdtFormatted: 16/07/2017 19:28:33 EDT
```

Answer (score 2):

### tl;dr

Never use a date-time parser/formatter type (class) without a `Locale`.

```
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String dateString = "16/07/2017 19:28:33 EST";
        final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);

        System.out.println(MessageFormat.format("Input - {0}", dateString));
        System.out.println(
                MessageFormat.format("Parsed - {0}", formatter.format(ZonedDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter))));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Input - 16/07/2017 19:28:33 EST
Parsed - 16/07/2017 19:28:33 EDT
```

<kbd>[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/sttrBS)</kbd>

Comment: Your Answer made me realize the input shown in the Question is actually incorrect, with `EST` rather than `EDT`.